# runtime HTML minification

Tags: compression, jsp

The processing time for my project on Google App Engine is about 20 ms for a JSP page. Using [HtmlCompressor](https://github.com/serg472/htmlcompressor/releases) at runtime (using a JSP tag) to minify the HTML, the processing time increases to about 100 ms. With (embedded) CSS minification turned on, it increases to about 200 ms. The overall size reduction of HTML is 1.6 KB (20 %).

Should I turn runtime minification on or off?

Some more details:

- With minification I mean removal of redundant whitespaces, etc. This is not about zipping, which is also done.
- The website is quite simple and used from both mobile and non-mobile devices.

Comment: What is the usage of your web application and what is the profile of your users?

Comment: It’s a “how to” website for a common topic.